# High resolution global land use projections

Tags: hydrology, land-surface, earth-system, land-surface-models

I am looking for global land use projections for a large scale hydrological analysis. The most widely used datasets are the [LUH (v1) Products used for CMIP5](http://luh.umd.edu/data.shtml) based on [Hurtt et al 2011](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10584-011-0153-2). These products have been recently updated for the preparation of the CMIP6 climate experiments (LUH v2).

LUH v1 products are available at a spatial resolution of 0.5 degrees. I am looking for something a little more detailed.

I am aware of a downscaling project implemented by researchers at CSIRO ([Hoskins et al 2016](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ece3.2104/full)). The output of this exercise is available as [Global 30s (~1km) resolution land use for 2005](https://data.csiro.au/dap/landingpage?pid=csiro%3A15276). Unfortunately, this dataset is available only for the year 2005.

Could anyone suggest a similar product, even a bit coarser (<=10 km resolution), for the future projections?

**EDIT**: the kind of data I'm looking for has to be based on CMIP5 LU projections (LUH v1) to ensure consistency with the Land Cover used for the climate projections (from the General Circulation of Earth System Models).
In case this does not exist, does anyone know an efficient algorithm I can use to downscale LUH v1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't 10km or less, the [CMIP6 dataset](http://luh.umd.edu/data.shtml) is released as of last week. It's now at 0.25degree spatial resolution which is an improvement.

Comment: I know about the cmip6 database, but it's still 0.25. Moreover it would be different from the land use used for the climate simulations: this would create problems with a picky reviewer. The CMIP6 climate projection won't be available before 2020. I need something based on CMIP5 experiment